# Wrong color-theme displayed

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, neovim

I recently saw [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5r6yzFEXajQ) video about `tmux and vim` and instantly fell in love with the color theme used in the video. Luckily the presenter (*Nick Nisi*) provides a link in the video-description to his `.vimrc` an more resources.

I looked through his GitHub repository and saw that he used a theme called *delek*. It seems like delek is preinstalled with vim, but I also found another download for it.

Well, my `vim`doesn't even look close to the `vim` as shown in the video. I't not sure whether I used a wrong theme or if I somehow screw up my colors. I'm using the Terminal-App under Mac, which supports 256 colors and I'm pretty sure that iTerm (that's what Nick uses in the video) *only* supports 256 colors as well. So this shouldn't be the problem...

I'm actually using `neoVim`, but this should't play a role neither. 
Here is my `.config/init.vim` (`neoVim`'s equivalent to `.vimrc`):

```
" Setup NeoBundle {{{
" If vundle is not installed, do it first

  " Install NeoBundle if not already installed
  let bundleExists = 1
  if (!isdirectory(expand("$HOME/.config/nvim/bundle/neobundle.vim")))
    call system(expand("mkdir -p $HOME/.nvim/bundle"))
    call system(expand("git clone https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim ~/.config/nvim/bundle/neobundle.vim"))
    let bundleExists = 0
  endif


  if 0 | endif

  if has('vim_starting')
    if &compatible
      " Be iMproved
      set nocompatible
  endif

" Required:
    set runtimepath+=~/.config/nvim//bundle/neobundle.vim/ 
  endif

" Required:
  call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.config/nvim/bundle/'))

" Let NeoBundle manage NeoBundle
" Required:
  NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'

" colorscheme & syntax highlighting
  NeoBundle 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/delek.vim'

  call neobundle#end()

" Required:
  filetype plugin indent on
  NeoBundleCheck
  if bundleExists == 0
    echo "Installing Bundles, ignore errors"
  endif

"}}}

" Themes {{{
  syntax on

  set encoding=utf8
  let base16colorspace=256
  set t_Co=256
  set background=dark
  colorscheme delek
"}}}

" Miscellaneous {{{
  set clipboard=unnamed
  set foldmethod=marker
"}}}
```

It would be awesome if anyone of you guys would know whether it's a problem with the terminal, the (probably) wrong theme or my config?

Comment: What does the `:set t_Co` command display? It should tell you how many colors vim thinks to be available. This may be wrong; you may try to force 256 colors with `:set t_Co=256`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help, but I just think I got a wrong color theme. I have no idea, where the right one is, but I just choose another one I like even more. If anyone knows the name of the theme he used in the video I'm happy to know it though.